# Как работает побитовый оператор сдвиг влево (<<)?

Tags: javascript, html, битовые-операции

В учебнике по JS есть такая фраза:"Оператор << сдвигает первый операнд на указанное число битов влево. Лишние биты отбрасываются, справа добавляются нулевые биты." К тому же упоминается, что "если крайний-левый бит равен 0 – число положительное, если 1 – число отрицательное. Поэтому этот бит называется знаковым битом." Если это всё так, тогда из пятой строчки кода разве не следует, что у меня изначально было дано отрицательное число (т.е. не 10000000000, а -10000000000) из чего выходит какой-то парадокс? И ещё, разве в девятой строчке единица не должна была отброситься (или можно отбрасывать только нули?)?

```
1.    <!DOCTYPE html>
2.    <html>
3.      <script>
4.          var mask=10000000000;
5.          var fly=mask.toString(2); //1001010100000010111110010000000000
6.          alert(fly);
7.          var zed=+mask<<1; //-1474836480
8.          alert(zed);
9.          var gid=zed.toString(2); //-1001010100000010111110010000000000
10.         alert(gid);
11.     </script>
12.   </html>
```

```js
var mask = 10000000000;
var fly = mask.toString(2); //1001010100000010111110010000000000
console.log(mask, fly);
var zed = +mask << 1; //-1474836480
var gid = zed.toString(2); //-1001010100000010111110010000000000
console.log(zed, gid);
```

Comment: @Igor, не, тут же про работу битовых операторов. Проблема как раз в том, что они в int32 сначала все переводят, поэтому и цифры такие получаются

Comment: @Igor, хотя и проблема с toString Тоже имеется...

Comment: @Grundy, то есть, если я правильно понимаю, происходит следующее: берётся число 1001010100000010111110010000000000 и сокращается до 32 битов, т.е. получится 01010100000010111110010000000000, а потом всё сдвигается на единицу и добавляется справа нуль: 10101000000101111100100000000000. Только мой ответ вновь не соответствует тому, что в консоли.

Comment: _Только мой ответ вновь не соответствует тому, что в консоли._ - просто ты не знаешь, что именно у тебя выведено в консоль :-) [`.toString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type) на самом деле делает немного другое